# Отдельная загрузка элементов страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток. Перечитал кучу статей, но так и не нашел подходящего решения.Трабл вот в чем:
На странице вставлено много видео с ютуба+картинки+аудио записи(через тег audio-html5)
Страница получается весомая. Пробывал всякие скрипты предзагрузки как на всю страницу целиком, так и к отдельным блокам-эффект тот же.
На картинки и прочие элементы срабатывает, а на видео с ютуба-нет. Подскажите решение. В идеале конечно сделать пост загрузку-отдельных элементов страницы.

Comment: А что насчет добавления элементов видео в HTML после того, как загружена страница? Чтобы верстка не разваливалась, контейнеры для видео могут быть видны сразу (в виде пустых блоков).

Comment: А каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: [Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/r6b0kbok/1/). Адекватно вставить видео я, пардон, так и не смог, но сама идея отражена правильно. Возможно, чтобы проверить работу fiddle корректно, нужно нажать "Run".

Comment: Ну лично у меня тоже не получилось.То есть страница загрузилась.ок.допустим я по клику начинаю загружать вмдосы(около 40 штук).и когда начинаю загружать-виснет браузер

Comment: Грузите не все сразу. Например, небольшими группами с задержкой между ними.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте скрыть часть элементов `style="display:none;"` и показывать только по запросу пользователя. В общем прячьте всё ненужное под спойлер

Comment: Это не причем.Видео с ютуба всеровно "грузит сайт".

Comment: Слайдер как в ВК, например, с загрузкой страницы через AJAX только тогда, когда пользователю это явно нужно

Comment: Приведите пример.Я выше в комментариях отписывался,что у меня пока никак не получается загружать такое кол-во видео.Что бы сайт не вис.Либо виснет сама страница во время загрузки,либо уже во время загрузки всех видосов

Comment: Так зачем же вы всё сразу грузите? Грузите по запросу пользователя. Если уж и тогда виснуть начнёт, то выгружайте из DOM то, что уже пользователю не нужно. Повторю, грузить конкретное видео только тогда, когда требует пользователь

Comment: В теории можно сделать так.Допустим есть див.У него ставим бэкграунд.или просто картинку с превью видео.Вешаем событие на онклик.При нажатии появляется надпись."подождите".И потом картинка заменяется ссылкой на видео.Но вот как на практике это реализовать я не знаю.Опыта в js практически нет.

Comment: ну вот. Совсем другое дело. Я думаю, вас любой поисковик покажет скрипт, решающий вашу проблему